# Answer true or false: For A and B sets, A ∩ B = B ∩ B'

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Answer true or false: For sets $A$ and $B:$  $A \cap B = B \cap B'.$

The statement is false. Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets with $A = B$ and let $X = \{ a , b , c \}.$ Then

$A \cap B = \{ a \} \cap \{ a \} = \{ a \} $  and  $B \cap B'= \{ a \} \cap \{ b , c\}.$ Since for all set $A, \emptyset \subseteq A$, note that  $\{ a \} \cap \{ b , c \} = \emptyset.$

But then $A \cap B \neq B \cap B'$ because $\{a\} \neq  \emptyset.$

> Is my answer correct? This is an exercise taken from my workbook.

Comment: I'm flummoxed they'd *ask* such a question. There'd be utterly no reason to think $A\cap B = B\cap B'$ and it obviously isn't true.  You might as well ask "$8+7 = 32$-- true or false". But, yes, your reasoning is correct.  However we don't know that $A\cap B$ is *never* equal to $B\cap B'$ (if $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ then $A\cap B$ *does* $= B\cap B'$); just that it doesn't *have* to equal $B\cap B'$.... Also what doeas $\emptyset \subset A$ have to do with your argument.

Comment: Note $B\cap B' = \{x\in B\}\cap \{x\not \in B\} = \{x| x\in B$ and $x\not\in B\} = \emptyset$ *always*.  So if if $A \cap B = B\cap B' \iff A\cap B = \emptyset \iff$ $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  As that need not be true the statement is false in general but not necessarily always  false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right but it needs to be written in a slightly better manner. For instance, you never write what $A$ actually is.

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $A=B= \{a\}.$ Then $$A\cap B=\{a\}\cap \{a\}=\{a\}$$ and $$B \cap B^c =\emptyset$$ and so $$A\cap B \neq B\cap B^c.$$

Comment: I so appreciate it . I am new mathmajor. Any words of advice for me? :D

Comment: @NewSelfTaughtMathematician Always be precise in what you're writing. Practice. Practice. Practice. Check and re-check your work.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this is correct. Though one shouldn't need to make an example to see it's false already: $B \cap B' = \emptyset$ regardless of what $B$ is, so the only way it could be true is if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ always, but that's obviously not always the case.

Though a minor typo, I believe you meant to say $A \cap B = \{a\} \cap \{a\}$ at the start. Same result though.

Comment: You are right! Hehehe, cheers!